# how to insert an array in mysql table in single column but different rows?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an array as follows :

```
                   array(1) {
                            [0]=>
                       array(4) {
                             [0]=>
                                string(4) "pink"
                             [1]=>
                                string(4) "blue"
                              [2]=>
                                string(3) "Red"
                              [3]=>
                                string(5) "white"
                               }
                          }
```

i want this pink to be inserted in to single row in my color column then next row blue ,red, white and so on. any help on how this can be achieved.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried something? Which API do you use?

Comment: something like .. `INSERT INTO table (color) values ("'" . implode("'),('", $colors) . "'");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You loop twice.

```
foreach($array as $subarray){
    foreach($subarray as $color){
        $query = "INSERT INTO tbl (color) VALUES (?)";
        //Rest of insert statement here.
    }
}
```

Comment: hey thanks a lot .. it works :D

Comment: @KetkiNimdeo if it works, check it as answer.